# Saber a quantidade de caracteres a partir do tamanho da coluna listview vb6

Tags: listview, visual-basic-6

Eu tenho uma api em vb6 responsável por gerar relatórios a partir de componentes do tipo listview. Acontece, que o relatório é composto por uma tabela com diversas colunas que são espelhadas no ListView. A medida da coluna no relatório é dada pelo número de caracteres que ela contem... exemplo:

Coluna2 = A coluna2 tem o tamanho de  7 caracteres no maximo.

Entretanto, que dar o tamanho da coluna do relatório baseada no do tamanho do texto exibido na coluna no listview. Ou seja, se eu reduzir o tamanho da coluna la no listivew e o texto ficar aparente como "Colu" ao inves de "Coluna2" então quero mandar o novo tamanho "Colu" = 4 para o meu relatório.

Mas fica dificil ter essa medida... como por exemplo, eu poderia saber quantos caracteres estao sendo exibidos dentro daquela coluna no listview? Considerando que tenha sido redimensionada pelo usuário e possa estar cortando algum texto pela metade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vc vai ter que usar a API do windows pra via *SendMessage*, questionar direto pra *handle* do *ListView* essas medidas. O VB6 não tem nativamente interfaces pra essas propriedades.

Tive o mesmo problema em um projeto, assim que achar o link ou o código, posto